# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'info' in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

i am crating social media share button https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/Guides/blob/master/all/social_share_links.md
trying this guide ant trying encode my model.info which is char field paste into status

```
<a  class="i-links" target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/home?status=I'm%20going%20to%20learn%20to%20Code...%20Come%20build%20an%20web%20apsp%20with%20me!%20%23CFE%20and%20@justinmitchel%20{{ request.build_absolute_uri|urlencoded }}">
```

trying

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode, quote_plus
def ttt_read(request, title):
    ttt = movie.objects.filter(urltitle=title)
    share_string = quote_plus(ttt.info)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Commentform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Thank You For Your Comment')
    else:
        form = Commentform()
    return render(request, 'ttt_read.html',{'ttt':ttt,'form':form,'share_string':share_string})
```

but when i tried to render it thows above mentioned error so what i am doing wrong here

Comment: do `ttt[0].info`

Comment: `share_string = quote_plus(ttt.first().info)` ttt is a list and info an attribute of an Object. so take the first element of your list and use `.info`